# How to handle null case in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

This my html code and below in my ts code ,

```
 <div id="address" class="bg-light rounded mt-3">
                <div class="h5 font-weight-bold text-primary"> Customer Feedback </div>
                <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-md-start align-items-md-center pt-3">
                    <div class="mr-auto"> <b>Purchase Feedback </b>
                        <p class="text-justify text-muted">{{description}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am getting this feedback from an api which I am storing in localstorge , but sometime its very much possible that this.feedbackdetails.description might be null , when the data is available it works fine but data is not available it gives error something like this

```
   this.feedbackdetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('feedback'))
    if (this.feedbackdetails.description != null) {
      this.description = this.feedbackdetails.description
    } else {
      this.description = 'NO FEEDBACK PROVIDED'
    }
```

ErrorMsg:-

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of null
    at GetcutomerorderdetailsComponent.push../src/app/getcutomerorderdetails/getcutomerorderdetails.component.ts.GetcutomerorderdetailsComponent.ngOnInit (main.js:1407)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (vendor.js:56990)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (vendor.js:65246
```

Is there any way to handle this ?

Comment: use `*ngIf="{feedbackdetails}"`, also, why do you have `thiss.description` and `this.descriptiondata`?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your if to handle the lack of this.feedbackdetails.description:

```
if(this.feedbackdetails && this.feedbackdetails.hasOwnProperty("description"))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case this would be enough, since you detect existance of value of description property (regardless if it exists or not)

```
if (this.feedbackdetails && this.feedbackdetails.description)
```

or simplified:

```
if (this.feedbackdetails?.description)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by giving a null check in the start

```
this.feedbackdetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('feedback'))
if(this.feedbackdetails){
  if (this.feedbackdetails.description != null) {
    this.description = this.feedbackdetails.description
  } else {
    this.description = 'NO FEEDBACK PROVIDED'
  }
}
```

or using `?` operator

```
if (this.feedbackdetails?.description != null) {
    this.description = this.feedbackdetails.description
  } else {
    this.description = 'NO FEEDBACK PROVIDED'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
this.feedbackdetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('feedback'))
this.description = this.feedbackdetails?.description ?? 'NO FEEDBACK PROVIDED';
```

this.feedbackdetails? would do the null/undefined validation and return 'NO F..' if null,

Else would check this.feedbackdetails.description, which if null/undefined, would again return 'NO F..', or the value even if it's ''/0/false.